# How to plot 2 sigma variation in a semilogy plot with python

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy, curve-fitting

I am trying to fit some sample data in a semilogy plot with curve_fit function from scipy. My best fit curve looks okay with the code I am following, but I am having trouble with the 2 sigma curves, which I want to show simultaneously along with the best fit curve and grey-filled. My code looks like the following:

```
import sys
import os
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import scipy.optimize as optimization

M = np.array([-2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3,4])
Y_z = np.array([0.05, 0.2, 3, 8, 50, 344, 2400 ])

# curve fit linear function
def line(x, a, b):
    return a*x+b

popt, pcov = curve_fit(line, M, np.log10(Y_z))     # change here

# plotting
plt.semilogy(M , Y_z, 'o')
plt.semilogy(M, 10**line(M, popt[0], popt[1]), ':', label = 'curve-fit')

# plot 1 sigma -error
y1 = 10**(line(M, popt[0] + pcov[0,0]**0.5, popt[1] - pcov[1,1]**0.5))
y2 = 10**(line(M, popt[0] - pcov[0,0]**0.5, popt[1] + pcov[1,1]**0.5))
plt.semilogy(M, y1, ':')
plt.semilogy(M, y2, ':')
plt.fill_between(M, y1, y2, facecolor="gray", alpha=0.15)

plt.xlabel(r"$\log X$")
plt.ylabel('Y')   
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Your help is very appreciated for the variance curves  [image]

Comment: what's your question?

Comment: I do not think I could plot 2 sigma variance curves along with the best fit curve. the curves intersect with the best fit, which I do not expect

Comment: You should edit your question to include your specific question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In principle, a linear fit doesn't need non-linear least-squares curve-fitting at all:  linear regression should work.

That said, to address your questions, you might find lmfit (http://lmfit.github.io/lmfit-py/) useful here.  It has a slightly higher-level and slightly more Pythonic approach to curve-fitting, and adds many features.  One of these is calculating the uncertainty in the result for a selected value of sigma.

To do your fit with lmfit, it would look like

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.optimize as optimization

import lmfit

M = np.array([-2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3,4])
Y_z = np.array([0.05, 0.2, 3, 8, 50, 344, 2400 ])

# curve fit linear function
def line(x, a, b):
    return a*x+b

# set up model and create parameters from model function
# note that function argument names are used for parameters
model = lmfit.Model(line)
params = model.make_params(a=1, b=0)

result = model.fit(np.log10(Y_z), params, x=M)

print(result.fit_report())
```

which will print out a report about the fit like this:

```
[[Model]]
    Model(line)
[[Fit Statistics]]
    # fitting method   = leastsq
    # function evals   = 8
    # data points      = 7
    # variables        = 2
    chi-square         = 0.10468256
    reduced chi-square = 0.02093651
    Akaike info crit   = -25.4191304
    Bayesian info crit = -25.5273101
[[Variables]]
    a:  0.77630819 +/- 0.02734470 (3.52%) (init = 1)
    b:  0.22311337 +/- 0.06114460 (27.41%) (init = 0)
[[Correlations]] (unreported correlations are < 0.100)
    C(a, b) = -0.447
```

You can calculate the 2-sigma uncertainty in the best-fit result as

```
# calculate 2-sigma uncertainty in result
del2 = result.eval_uncertainty(sigma=2, x=M)
```

and then use this and the fit results to plot the results (slightly modified from your form):

```
plt.plot(M, np.log10(Y_z), 'o', label='data')
plt.plot(M, result.best_fit, ':',  label = 'curve-fit')  
plt.fill_between(M, result.best_fit-del2, result.best_fit+del2, facecolor="grey", alpha=0.15)

plt.xlabel(r"$\log X$")
plt.ylabel('Y')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

which should produce a plot like

[image]

hope that helps.

Comment: THat is very helpful, specially knowing about that lmfit function.